# Bootstrap - "text-center text-md-left" - the break point is not working and text always is aligned to the center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm just learning and using bootstrap to practice, however I ran into an issue. I have this div, and I want when the display is small then the text should align to the center, on bigger screens it should be aligned to the left.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="product-image" class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid" id="product" src="img/product.png" alt="" width=300px style="padding-top:250px; padding-bottom:100px;filter:brightness(90%);">
            </div>

            <div id="product-description" class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="text-center text-md-left">
                    <img src="img/icons/menu.png" alt="Menu" width="25px">
                    <h6 class="text-light">text1</h6>
                    <h6 class="text-light">text2</h6>
                    <h6 class="text-light">text3</h6>
                    <h6 class="text-light">text4</h6>
                    <h6 class="text-light">text5</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

However when I add text-center, the text automatically aligns to the center and refuses to align to the left no matter what infix I use.

HOWEVER if I do "text-left text-md-center" It works the, but it's the opposite way I need. If I change it again to `text-center text-md-left`, then the text is centered no matter what.

I spent a good two hours trying to figure out, trying different ways of doing it but still no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. You're using classes which are obsolete in the current version. Since left alignment is the _default_ this may explain the behavior you're seeing.